# Regex for to force special title format

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I am using AngularJS/javascript to force titles in an special format, the titles should be in the format

```
C#[##]-DW##-MP###[-D][d] // Format cabinets
B#[##]-FD###-FL###[-D][d] // Format boxes
T#[##]-MP###[-D][d] // Format tubes
```

What I've tried so far was the following:
`C\d\[\d\d\]-[A-Z]W\d\d-MP\d{3}\[-[A-Z]\]\[[a-z]\]`

But with the above regex, I cannot get matching groups working.

The requirements I am using to build up my pattern is the following:

- Characters in [ ] are optional
- d – variable lowercase alpha character
- D – variable uppercase alpha character
- # – variable numeric character with leading zeros if number of digits is less than number of consecutive symbols.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Turns out I need to use 3 expressions anyway, like so

```
T\d\[\d{2}\]-MP\d{3}\[-[A-Z]\]\[[a-z]\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/etwLuTkXSv31RiWi)

```
C\d\[\d{2}\]-[A-Z]W\d{2}-MP\d{3}\[-[A-Z]\]\[[a-z]\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SszdxTbIUHKAMwN7)

```
T\d\[\d{2}\]-MP\d{3}\[-[A-Z]\]\[[a-z]\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/RCLchSFSYSvDrl9G)

Comment: @Siguza thanks for contributing absolutely nothing.

Comment: I think that's an appropriate response to "I want you to write my code because I don't know how and haven't bothered to look it up".

Comment: @JeffC you mean like this? `\d\[\d{2}\]-[A-Z]W\d{2}-MP\d{3}\[-[A-Z]\]\[[a-z]\]` .. for cabinets

Comment: @karthikmanchala that's more like it. Mine was quite a mess, haha. If you want to response below I will mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: @Siguza nope, not even close but again, thanks for the useless contributions. I am sure you're fun at parties.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a [“Give me a regex that does X”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733/2302862) question.

Comment: @Siguza that's nice but that is not at all what it is, to reflect that, I have updated the question my regex that i was attempting to use. Perhaps you need a hobby instead of trolling peoples questions.

Comment: @JeffC That comment was auto-generated, I don't get off over sticking my opinion into other people's face. But this question is 1) a bad question for Q&A because it handles exactly one example and nothing else, and is therefore of very little to no value for any future reader. 2) It is likely to attract bad answers, i.e. the given solution might work perfectly, but there is no explanation provided at all as to how or why the provided solution works, so it is very hard to learn from it. 3) Your original question shows absolutely no research or effort whatsoever, and thus looks like you just...

Comment: ...demand others to provide you with a solution for free, which is very unwelcome on StackOverflow, and makes you appear enormously pretentious to say the least. Now, editing your attempt into the question makes a big difference, as it separates you from the horde of people who think StackOverflow is a place where other people work for them. In terms of research/effort I'd say it's an OK question now. I'm still leaving the close vote, as this question is very unlikely to help anyone else, but since you have a solution, that shouldn't hurt too much.

Comment: @Siguza please stay on topic, you're clearly upset about nothing. If you feel the need to discuss this further PM me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

For C :

```
\d\[\d{2}\]-[A-Z]W\d{2}-MP\d{3}\[-[A-Z]\]\[[a-z]\]
```

For B:

```
\d\[\d{2}\]-F[A-Z]\d{3}-FL\d{3}\[-[A-Z]\]\[[a-z]\]
```

For T:

```
\d\[\d{2}\]-MP\d{3}\[-[A-Z]\]\[[a-z]\]
```

Comment: Tested and confirmed in Debuggex!

Comment: T\d\[\d{2}\]-MP\d{3}\[-[A-Z]\]\[[a-z]\]

![Regular expression visualization](https://www.debuggex.com/i/qZT50CbtHCX3_fm9.png)

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qZT50CbtHCX3_fm9)